# plot.gam partial effects plot: is there another function to plot more than one variable?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, smoothing

The [package description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l93UA.png) of plot.gam describes under Warning: "The function can not deal with smooths of more than 2 variables!" My gam model has a base model that includes habitat variables, which I am able to plot using plot.gam. I have additional terms in my gam model for interactions. Is there a way to show the partial effects of these interactions as you are able to view with plot.gam for just the smooth of one variable? Is there a way to best visualize interactions, to plot like what plot.gam plots?

Example code for fly counts below, covariates explained:
canyonsize=factor, small or large;
pool=factor, presence or absence;
distance=continuous, upstream length;
streamtype=factor,coded fpr 1-5 different streams;
year=factor, 4 years.

I would like to plot the base habitat model or main effects of length, depth, boulders, width, and pool. Perhaps canyon size should be added via "by=" instead of as a second variable? There are two attempts of the final model, model 2 may fare better.

###### gam model 1

```
fl_mod1 <- gam(flies~ 
   te(length,canyonsize,bs=c("cr","re"),k=c(10,10))+#basehabmodel
              te(depth,canyonsize,bs=c("cr","re"),k=c(10,10))+
              te(boulders,canyonsize,bs=c("cr","re"),k=c(10,10))+
              te(width,canyonsize,bs=c("cr","re"),k=c(10,10))+
              te(pool,canyonsize,bs=c("re","re"),k=c(10,10))+
```

te(distance,streamtype,year,bs=c("cr","re","re"),k=c(10,10,10)),#interaction

```
            data=flycountshab,
            family=nb(link = "log"),
            method="REML",optimizer=c("outer","bfgs"))
```

###### gam model 2

```
fl_mod1 <- gam(flies~ 
              canyonsize+
              s(length,by=canyonsize,bs=cr,k=10)+#basehabmodel
              s(depth,by=canyonsize,bs=cr,k=10)+
              s(boulders,by=canyonsize,bs=cr,k=10)+
              s(width,by=canyonsize,bs=cr,k=10)+
              s(pool,by=canyonsize,bs=re,k=10)+
              
              streamtype+
              s(distance,bs=cr,k=10)+
              s(year,bs=re,k=10)+
              te(distance, year, by=streamtype,bs=c("cr","re"),k=c(10,10), m=1),#interaction
            
            data=flycountshab,
            family=nb(link = "log"),
            method="REML",optimizer=c("outer","bfgs"))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: plot.gam can now handle smooths of up to 4 variables now. I am not following what you want. Can you show the code for the `gam()` call so I can see what variables you have and how they enter the model, and then can you explain which terms you want to plot.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thank you. I added the code for the full gam model. I would like to plot the base habitat model or main effects of length, depth, boulders, width, and pool. Perhaps canyon size (factor: small, large) should be added via "by=" instead of as a second variable?

Comment: @GavinSimpson I added two examples for the gam(). The second may fare better.

Comment: If `canyonsize` is a factor you can't do `te(width, canyonsize, ...)` so *gam model 1* doesn't make sense.  In *gam model 2*, apart from the `te(distance, year, by = streamtype)` being better handled as a `ti()` (in which case the `s(distance)` and `s(year)` perobably need `by = streamtype` too, nothing in that model strikes me as being something `plot.gam` can't handle. `by` factor terms just make {mgcv} create multiple separate smooths; apart from some internal bookkeeping to record that it is a by smooth and what level it relates to, {mgcv} treats these as separate smooths

Comment: In that sense, your models are really just full of lots of univariate and bivariate smooths, which have been handled in {mgcv} for as long as I have been using the package. If something isn't working or you don't like what `plot.gam()` is doing, please include some output and explain what the problem is.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thanks I was able to run the recommended full model, runs slowly (4K+ observations, multiple years). How can one speed up the process besides using optimizer? Regarding plot.gam() for a simpler model (not full model), the best combination of K values via gam.check produced a very wiggly response for depth (PlotA). Can this partial effect be true? The default Ks had a smoother depth (PlotB). If depth is this wiggly, what does this mean for depth and the abundance of flies, interpretation wise? What about the association between distance and flies, which also has wiggles?

Comment: re speeding up, look at the help page for parallel computation with mgcv https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/mgcv-parallel.html and consider different ways to speed up computation. `bam()` might be an option. I have rarely needed to change the optimizer and I wouldn't do so for speed issues *unless* those speed issues were being caused by problems with fitting - which you might note but turning on output tracing; see ?gam.control